# CSS Blur background issue

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to have it so that the background of my text has a blur applied and having some issues.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Here's the code I am currently using.

```
.background-image {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;

 display: block;
 background-image: url('http://www.example.com/image/image.png');

 -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
 -moz-filter: blur(10px);
 -o-filter: blur(10px);
 -ms-filter: blur(10px);
 filter: blur(10px);
}
#track {
  z-index: 9999;    
}
```

As you can see in the screen shot above, it pushes the background image upwards instead of placing it behind my actual content.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle.

Comment: `z-index:`, `left:`, and `right:` mean *nothing* unless you also have a `position:` property.

Comment: @scott I messed around with position absolute, but it just made an even bigger mess making the background go over my content appose to going upwards...

Comment: All I'm saying is all the other CSS properties I point out do nothing without the position property. Literally nothing, I'm not making that up. And "absolute" is *not* the only position property one can use.

Comment: Provide a fiddle please.

Comment: @HermLuna I provided a link below in one of the comments, I believe the issue is due to something else on my theme, so providing a fiddle wouldn't be very helpful.

Comment: Providing a fiddle would be helpful to see if we got the same problem, that way we could verify it was indeed something in your theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap that inside a `container` and try as below, assign `position:absolute` to `.track` element.

```css
.background-image {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
 display: block;
 background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
 -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
 -moz-filter: blur(10px);
 -o-filter: blur(10px);
 -ms-filter: blur(10px);
 filter: blur(10px);
 width:100%;
 height:400px;
}
.track {
  z-index: 9999;    
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}

#container{
  width:80%;
  height:400px;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="track">
<h1>
Content
</h1>
</div>
<div class="background-image">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty much already answered the same thing with position:absolute... the container isn't really necessary.

Comment: @brld it's good option to wrap that inside a container or parent div as he is using image later-on it won't overflows out of it.

Comment: fair point. I don't think overflow is too much of a concern here but there's really no harm in putting it in a container.

Comment: @vin to set background position use background-position:center top;

Answer (score 0):

If your text is pushing the background image up, use:

```
position: absolute
```

That will make it so that the text is removed from the normal "flow" of the rest of the elements and they will no longer push or be pushed by any other elements. Note that you will have to manually position it now as it is not affected by any other elements.

Experiment around with position:absolute here! http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_absolute

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are blurring the background using the current technique. To blur your text add this class to your text.

```
.blur-text
{
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
```